# When changing html via element.innerHTML='text' it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

For the last hour or so, I've been trying to solve a problem, which came up when I tried to change html of an element from XMLHttpRequest.

```
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('notifications-navbar').innerHTML);
    document.getElementById('notifications-navbar').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(document.getElementById('notifications-navbar').innerHTML);
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

The output of the console logs were:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nCpaU1sx)

So in the console.log we can see the change to the innerHTML was made, however there is no change whatsoever when I have a look on the elements via Chrome inspect and also there is no change in the browser. I even tried to remove every other JS scripts that were being loaded and just make a simple change of the innerHTML outside of XHLHttpRequest, but that didn't help too. Please if you could help I would be really happy.

Comment: And you're sure `notifications-navbar` isn't being changed by something else?

Comment: Yes I am sure, at least I don't know about any other JS script that could be changing it, and also I tried disabling every other JS script and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your EndPoint URL is , but I wrote this for you and it works just fine. Hope this can help you!

**HTML**

```
<div id = "notifications-navbar"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var xhr;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(document.getElementById('notifications-navbar').innerHTML);
            document.getElementById('notifications-navbar').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(document.getElementById('notifications-navbar').innerHTML);
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
```

Comment: Well, thank you, it works in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dba9uaen/) just fine. However, this is almost identical to mine, however mine code doesn't work properly, even if it is the same. Well it doesn't work for the element `notifications-navbar`, but works fine for body element for example. Should I also try to share my source code?

Comment: I found my mistake, but I am thankful for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry guys, I found my mistake, I had in my HTML two elements with ID notifications-navbar and only the first one was being changed. Thanks for your help anyway.